# what's means of jinfo non-default vm flags

Tags: jvm, jinfo

[image]

what's means of `jinfo` non-default vm flags?  non-default is an ambiguous, I think it looks like default vm flags.

Answer (score 4):

`jinfo` prints those VM flags which value is either overridden by a command-line option or set by the VM ergonomics policy. In other words - the flags with a value different from the built-in default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I find jvm built-in default value?